# Store very huge data in txt file format with Tab Separated values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text-files

I am loading the dataset from SQL DB by using `pd.read_sql()`. I tried to store 100 million rows and 300 columns in an excel/csv file. But it failed due to the limitation of 1,048,576 rows.

So I am trying to store the same file as `.tsv` file using

```
pd.to_csv("data.txt", header=True, index=False, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

I dont find the limitation of tab separated txt file.

is it good to go or is there any other good option?

Comment: There is no limit in txt file to store the data. but it will cost lots to re-read it. so you can save every 1million ~ 100million rows to a file depending you need.

Comment: I need the complete data to do an analysis.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing here that I am not sure about is how `pandas` internally works. Besides that, your approach is totally fine. Hadoop widely uses `.tsv` format to store and process data. And there is no such thing like "the limitation of `.tsv` file". A file is just a sequence of bytes. `\t` and `\n` are just characters without any differences. The limitation you encountered is imposed by Microsoft Excel, not by OS. For example, it was lower a long time ago and other spread sheet applications could impose different limitations.

If you `open('your_file.tsv', 'wt')` and `readline`, bytes until `\n` are just taken. Nothing else happens. There is no such thing like how many `\t`s are allowed until `\n`, how many `\n`s are allowed in a file. They are all just bytes and a file can take as much as characters allowed by OS.

It varies across different OSs, however, according to [NTFS vs FAT vs exFAT](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm), the maximum file size of an NTFS file system is almost 16TB. But in real, splitting a big file into multiple files of a reasonable size is a good idea. For example, you can easily distribute them.

To process such big data, you should take iterative or distributed approach. For example, Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a good idea. Your limitation is your machines memory since pandas loads everything into memory. A dataframe of that size won't fit. You probably need more machines and a distributed computing framework like apache spark or dask.

Alternatively, dependending on what you want to do with the data, you might not need to load it to memory.

Comment: Dear friend, I have tried 40% of the same data to save in local. the file size is only 170MB. So the total size might be not more than a GB.. and I am using 8GB RAM machine.

Comment: then you might be good to go, just give it a try, an monitor your memory. You can't break anything, just keyboard interrupt if you run out of memory